# PHP/MySQL echo links

Tags: php

I've looked all over Google for some examples of this, but I just can't seem to find a solution! Either they're going for an internal URL (with a dynamic ID pointing to a page, etc.) Basically all the other questions are about links that are more complex than what I'm going for.

Basically I have a table with 2 fields - name, and URL. (the page is a secret santa page where users can share their Amazon wish lists and view other users lists)

I want the URL to echo a link to the proper amazon wishlist URL.. here's my code:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:post';
$dbuser = 'db_user';
$dbpass = 'db_pass';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$sql = 'SELECT name, url FROM santa';

mysql_select_db('rev_phoenix');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    echo "<b>Username:</b> {$row['name']}  <br> ".
         "<b>Wishlist:</b> {$row['url']} <br> ".
         "<hr>";
} 
echo "Merry Christmas!\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You've said what you want the code to do, but not what the problem with it is. Do you get a white screen? An error message? Does it display the wrong thing? The right thing, in the wrong way?

Comment: no, the way it is in this code everything works beautifully.. except the 'url' part of the echo isn't actually linking to the link specified in the db entry. I've tried adding "a href" in several different ways.. I feel like I'm missing something else! Please excuse my noobism lol

Comment: btw ignore " $dbhost = 'localhost:post'; " - I meant to type port when I hid my db info

Comment: Try this `"<b>Wishlist:</b><a href="$row['url']}"> {$row['url']}</a> <br>"`   ?

Comment: You need to escape the "-s, since they're actually meant to be outputted. Try: 
`"<b>Wishlist:</b> <a href=\"{$row['url']}\">{$row['url']}</a> <br>"`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, `mysql` has been depricated as of PHP 5.5.0

You may want to go with using `mysqli`

Try using this for your code:

```
<?php
  $dbhost = 'localhost:post';
  $dbuser = 'db_user';
  $dbpass = 'db_pass';
  $dbcurrent = 'rev_phoenix';
  $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbcurrent);
  if(! $conn ) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
  }

  //Added order by random, and limit 1 to only show 1 'secret' santa.
  $sql = 'SELECT name, url FROM santa ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1';

  $retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $conn );
  if(! $retval ) {
    die( 'Could not get data: ' . mysqli_error($conn) );
  }
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($retval) {
    echo "<b>Username:</b> ". $row['name'] . "<br> ".
    "<b>Wishlist:</b> <a href='" . $row['url'] . "'>List</a><br>".
    "<hr>";
  } 
  echo "Merry Christmas!\n";
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: another white screen unfortunately. Is it because I need to install  this new version of mysql(i) on my server?

Comment: When you get a "white screen", look for your error logs.

Comment: haha you're going to think I'm an idiot... but how does one go about doing that?

Comment: If you're running this from your local machine, it's probably be at ``/var/log/error_log``

Comment: I just changed the one line and it worked <a href='" . $row['url'] . "'>List</a>